# Xcode crashes every time when it’s opening

Tags: ios, crash, storyboard, xcode7, flowlayout

After updating Xcode 7.0.1, I’m not able to open my workspace, every time it’s crashes. After reading all this text I understand it’s about flow layout of collection view, and some negative value. Let's say I don’t have chance to go back to Xcode 6. Does anyone has similar problem, or know how to fix this?

**exception :**

```
negative sizes are not supported in the flow layout
```

**about my workspace :**

using

- cocoapods
- storyboards
- auto layout (pure layout in some files)
- size classes not checked

**OS**
OS X 10.11 (macosx10.11):

Here is the crash log :

> XCODE VERSION INFO:
>
> Version = 7.0.1 (7A1001) Plugin Version = 8191 Beta Version = 0 OS
>   Version = 10.10.5 (14F27)
>
> ASSERTION:
>
> Failed to determine the values for ibLayoutInset,
>   intrinsicContentSize, baselineOffsetFromBottom,
>   firstBaselineOffsetFromTop, ibLayoutMargins, ibContentSize,
>   ibCellFrames, ibSectionHeaderViewFrames, ibSectionFooterViewFrames,
>   and ibBackgroundViewFrame of IBUICollectionView.
>
> Exception name: NSInternalInconsistencyException Exception reason:
>   negative sizes are not supported in the flow layout Exception
>   backtrace:
>     0. CoreFoundation           0x00000001033d5f4d __exceptionPreprocess
>   1. libobjc.A.dylib          0x0000000102e4fdeb objc_exception_throw
>
> 2. CoreFoundation           0x00000001033d5dca +[NSExceptionraise:format:arguments:]
> 3. Foundation               0x0000000102a9dae2 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:]
> 4. UIKit                    0x00000001010db6ff -[UICollectionViewFlowLayout _getSizingInfos]
> 5. UIKit                    0x00000001010dcef5 -[UICollectionViewFlowLayout _fetchItemsInfoForRect:]
> 6. UIKit                    0x00000001010d669d -[UICollectionViewFlowLayout prepareLayout]
> 7. UIKit                    0x00000001010f6ef1 -[UICollectionViewData _prepareToLoadData]
> 8. UIKit                    0x00000001010f767a -[UICollectionViewData validateLayoutInRect:]
> 9. UIKit                    0x00000001010a883e -[UICollectionView layoutSubviews]
>
>    10. UIKit                    0x000000010094911c -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:]
>    11. QuartzCore               0x00000001028bd36a -[CALayer layoutSublayers]
>    12. QuartzCore               0x00000001028b1bd0 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE
>    13. UIKit                    0x0000000100938d7b -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded]
>    14. IBCocoaTouchToolFoundation 0x00000001007c6920 -[UIView(IBCocoaTouchToolIntegration) awakeAfterMarshallerDidEstablishRelationshipsWithContext:populatingWarningMessages:]
>    15. IBCocoaTouchToolFoundation 0x00000001007e72ab -[IBCocoaTouchToolObjectPackage initWithRequest:globalMarshallingContext:]
>    16. IBCocoaTouchToolFoundation 0x00000001007e4533 +[IBCocoaTouchToolObjectPackage objectPackageFromRequest:]
>    17. IBCocoaTouchToolFoundation 0x00000001007c321e -[IBCocoaTouchTool _objectFromRequest:]
>    18. IBCocoaTouchToolFoundation 0x00000001007c361e -[IBCocoaTouchTool valuesForKeyPaths:ofMarshalledObjectRequest:resultMarshallerClassNames:resultMarshallerContexts:]
>    19. IBFoundation             0x00000001026cc54f __80-[IBMessageReceiveChannel deliverMessage:toTarget:withArguments:context:result:]_block_invoke
>    20. IBFoundation             0x00000001026cc25f -[IBMessageReceiveChannel deliverMessage:toTarget:withArguments:context:result:]
>    21. IBFoundation             0x00000001026cbf58 __88-[IBMessageReceiveChannel runBlockingReceiveLoopNotifyingQueue:notifyingTarget:context:]_block_invoke
>    22. libdispatch.dylib        0x00000001070ad4a7 _dispatch_client_callout
>    23. libdispatch.dylib        0x0000000107098f9b _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow_invoke
>    24. libdispatch.dylib        0x00000001070ad4a7 _dispatch_client_callout
>    25. libdispatch.dylib        0x0000000107097fc9 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
>    26. CoreFoundation           0x00000001033363e9 **CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE**
>    27. CoreFoundation           0x00000001032f7939 __CFRunLoopRun
>    28. CoreFoundation           0x00000001032f6e98 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
>    29. Foundation               0x0000000102a3d891 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:]
>    30. IBFoundation             0x00000001026a9c94 -[IBAbstractPlatformTool startServingReceiveChannel:]
>    31. IBFoundation             0x00000001026a9e70 -[IBAbstractPlatformTool startServingWriteDescriptor:readDescriptor:]
>    32. IBFoundation             0x00000001026aa97a +[IBAbstractPlatformTool main]
>    33. ???                      0x0000000100743bc7 ???
>    34. libdyld.dylib            0x00000001070dc92d start Exception info:{ }
>
>    EXCEPTION :
>
> negative sizes are not supported in the flow layout
>
> ```
> EXCEPTION BACKTRACE
> ```
>
> 1. CoreFoundation           0x00000001033d5f4d __exceptionPreprocess
> 2. libobjc.A.dylib          0x0000000102e4fdeb objc_exception_throw
> 3. CoreFoundation           0x00000001033d5dca +[NSException raise:format:arguments:]
> 4. Foundation               0x0000000102a9dae2 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:]
> 5. UIKit                    0x00000001010db6ff -[UICollectionViewFlowLayout _getSizingInfos]
> 6. UIKit                    0x00000001010dcef5 -[UICollectionViewFlowLayout _fetchItemsInfoForRect:]
> 7. UIKit                    0x00000001010d669d -[UICollectionViewFlowLayout prepareLayout]
> 8. UIKit                    0x00000001010f6ef1 -[UICollectionViewData _prepareToLoadData]
> 9. UIKit                    0x00000001010f767a -[UICollectionViewData validateLayoutInRect:]
> 10. UIKit                    0x00000001010a883e -[UICollectionView layoutSubviews]
>
>     10. UIKit                    0x000000010094911c -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:]
>     11. QuartzCore               0x00000001028bd36a -[CALayer layoutSublayers]
>     12. QuartzCore               0x00000001028b1bd0 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE
>     13. UIKit                    0x0000000100938d7b -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded]
>     14. IBCocoaTouchToolFoundation 0x00000001007c6920 -[UIView(IBCocoaTouchToolIntegration) awakeAfterMarshallerDidEstablishRelationshipsWithContext:populatingWarningMessages:]
>     15. IBCocoaTouchToolFoundation 0x00000001007e72ab -[IBCocoaTouchToolObjectPackage initWithRequest:globalMarshallingContext:]
>     16. IBCocoaTouchToolFoundation 0x00000001007e4533 +[IBCocoaTouchToolObjectPackage objectPackageFromRequest:]
>     17. IBCocoaTouchToolFoundation 0x00000001007c321e -[IBCocoaTouchTool _objectFromRequest:]
>     18. IBCocoaTouchToolFoundation 0x00000001007c361e -[IBCocoaTouchTool valuesForKeyPaths:ofMarshalledObjectRequest:resultMarshallerClassNames:resultMarshallerContexts:]
>     19. IBFoundation             0x00000001026cc54f __80-[IBMessageReceiveChannel deliverMessage:toTarget:withArguments:context:result:]_block_invoke
>     20. IBFoundation             0x00000001026cc25f -[IBMessageReceiveChannel deliverMessage:toTarget:withArguments:context:result:]
>     21. IBFoundation             0x00000001026cbf58 __88-[IBMessageReceiveChannel runBlockingReceiveLoopNotifyingQueue:notifyingTarget:context:]_block_invoke
>     22. libdispatch.dylib        0x00000001070ad4a7 _dispatch_client_callout
>     23. libdispatch.dylib        0x0000000107098f9b _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow_invoke
>     24. libdispatch.dylib        0x00000001070ad4a7 _dispatch_client_callout
>     25. libdispatch.dylib        0x0000000107097fc9 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
>     26. CoreFoundation           0x00000001033363e9 **CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE**
>     27. CoreFoundation           0x00000001032f7939 __CFRunLoopRun
>     28. CoreFoundation           0x00000001032f6e98 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
>     29. Foundation               0x0000000102a3d891 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:]
>     30. IBFoundation             0x00000001026a9c94 -[IBAbstractPlatformTool startServingReceiveChannel:]
>     31. IBFoundation             0x00000001026a9e70 -[IBAbstractPlatformTool startServingWriteDescriptor:readDescriptor:]
>     32. IBFoundation             0x00000001026aa97a +[IBAbstractPlatformTool main]
>     33. ???                      0x0000000100743bc7 ???
>     34. libdyld.dylib            0x00000001070dc92d start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into the storyboard or nib that has the negative value and modify the xml?

Comment: Thank you @Rohan Panchal for answer. Of course it's possible, but to giving negative value is absolutely valid in Xcode right? Also in my case, in layout window there is "no negative value" (not like exception says...). Maybe somewhere else. But again remember iOS 6-7 deltas, did we use negative values or not? I'm not able to open Xcode because it's crashes when I try to open project, but I'll double check with text editor.